# Trouble with alignment in html and css

Tags: html, css, header, navbar

I'm trying to write the code for a fitness supplement webshop, and as I am making the navigation bar, this weird problem has come up. The unordered list is neither aligned vertically nor horizontally.

[image: My problem in a photo]

**HTML:**

```
      <div class="menus">
        <ul menuList>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="menuLinks">SUPPLEMENTER</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="menuLinks">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="menuLinks">TØJ</a></li>
          <li><a href="signup.html">ANDET</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menus {
  background-color: #00C9FF;

  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;

  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;

  justify-content: center;

  bottom: 0%;
}

.menus ul li {
  list-style: none;

  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.menus ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;

  margin-top: auto;
}

.menus ul li a {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 30pt;

  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you needed this:

```css
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .menus {
    background-color: #00C9FF;

    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    justify-content: center;

    bottom: 0%;
  }

  .menus ul li {
    list-style: none;

    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
  }

  .menus ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    margin-top: auto;
  }

  .menus ul li a {
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 30pt;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;

  }
```

```html
<div class="menus">
  <ul menuList>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="menuLinks">SUPPLEMENTER</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menuLinks">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menuLinks">TØJ</a></li>
    <li><a href="signup.html">ANDET</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then the body margin was not set to 0 and the navbar needed a little bit more of height.

And yes... that code is not responsive.

Comment: How would you make the code responsive in this situation? by using percentages or? 

EDIT:
I have just tried to make the body margin 0, but this hasn't fixed the problem

Comment: Well that's another pair of shoes... Responsive layout is made with css.... if you are not a web designer and you don't create css templates why don't you use bootstrap or foundation... or even better some complete template from themeforest.net

Comment: I'm actually doing this project to learn since I'm not that great at web development. Btw; do you know how to fix the problem with my navbar?

Comment: Here you go.... the basics: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_col-s

media queries are the key, they make design responsive
`@media only screen and...`